# Inheritance : override in class constructor

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

I am reading the example in this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_classes_objects.htm
**Example :**

```
class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {
   var x: Int = xc
   var y: Int = yc
   def move(dx: Int, dy: Int) {
      x = x + dx
      y = y + dy
      println ("Point x location : " + x);
      println ("Point y location : " + y);
   }
}

class Location(override val xc: Int, override val yc: Int,
   val zc :Int) extends Point(xc, yc){
   var z: Int = zc

   def move(dx: Int, dy: Int, dz: Int) {
      x = x + dx
      y = y + dy
      z = z + dz
      println ("Point x location : " + x);
      println ("Point y location : " + y);
      println ("Point z location : " + z);
   }
}

object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val loc = new Location(10, 20, 15);

      // Move to a new location
      loc.move(10, 10, 5);
   }
}
```

I didn't understand the utility of override keyword in class location constructor !
Why it is mentioned since we have an extends here ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
scala> class A(val a: Int)
defined class A
```

If you try to define `B` like this:

```
scala> class B(val a: Int) extends A(a)
<console>:11: error: overriding value a in class A of type Int;
 value a needs `override' modifier
       class B(val a: Int) extends A(a)
```

compiler complains because it looks like you are trying to define a member `a` in class `B` and it already exists there through inheritance (from `A`). You need to add `override` to be explicit about your intentions in this case:

```
scala> class B(override val a: Int) extends A(a)
defined class B
```

More specifically you don't have to provide an `override` if you are overriding abstract members:

```
scala> trait A { def a: Int }
defined trait A

scala> class B(override val a: Int) extends A
defined class B

scala> class B(val a: Int) extends A
defined class B
```

However, to avoid unintended overrides when mixing in traits Scala protects you by requiring explicit `override`.

Consider this example:

No problem here:

```
scala> trait A { def a: Int = 1 }
defined trait A

scala> class B
defined class B

scala> new B with A
res0: B with A = $anon$1@3e29739a
```

You are saved from ambiguity:

```
scala> trait A { def a: Int = 1 }
defined trait A

scala> class B { def a: Int = 2 }
defined class B

scala> new B with A
<console>:13: error: <$anon: B with A> inherits conflicting members:
  method a in class B of type => Int  and
  method a in trait A of type => Int
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in <$anon: B with A>.)
       new B with A
           ^
```

Resolve the conflict manually:

```
scala> trait A { def a: Int = 1 }
defined trait A

scala> class B { def a: Int = 2 }
defined class B

scala> new B with A { override val a = super[B].a }
res6: B with A{val a: Int} = $anon$1@76f6896b
```